# How do I verify that a set is an affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having trouble with this exercise in one of my text books
Let $\mathbf{x, y}\in\mathbb{R}^4$, and let $L$ be a set such that
$L = \{\alpha \mathbf{x} +\beta\mathbf{y}: \alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{R}, \alpha+\beta=1\}$

Show that $L$ is an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$

I am quite stuck on this exercise. I know that if some vectors let's call them $l_1$, and $l_2$ are in $L$ then so is any affine combination. I don't really know how to get further than that.

Would you do something like

$l_1 = \alpha_1\mathbf{x}_1+\beta_1\mathbf{y}_1$ and $l_2 =\alpha_2\mathbf{x}_2+\beta_2\mathbf{y}_2$

and put this into an affine combination. How would you then show that this affine combination is in $L$?

Any help would be great.

Comment: What’s an affine combination?

Comment: Hello, welcome. Try $\alpha=\frac12$ and $\beta=\frac12$

Comment: ... and let $L$ be $\color{red}{\text{the}}$ set ...

Comment: What is your definition of an affine subspace?

Comment: @ronno. I wanted the OP to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

First, an affine subspace is of the form $A+V$, where $A$ is a point, and $V$ a linear subspace.

Here, with $A=:x$ and $V:=\mathbb R (y-x)$, it is not difficult to verify that $L=A+V$, using $\alpha + \beta = 1$.

Let $\beta \in \mathbb R$ and $\alpha=1-\beta. \alpha x +\beta y=(1-\beta)x+\beta y=x+\beta (y-x)\in L.$